# Spectral theorem for representations proof.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, spectral-theory

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space, and $U$ a unitary representation of $\mathbb{Z}^d$ on $H$. Let $\chi_m$ be the characters of the Torus $T^d$, and $m$ the Haar measure on $T^d$. I would like to Show that if $U$ is cyclic with cyclic vector $v$, then there is a finite measure $\mu_v$ on $T^d$ such that $\langle U(m)v,v\rangle=\int_{T^d}\chi_m d\mu_v$. I would like to do this by considering the sequence of measure on $T^d$ defined by $d\mu_{v,N}=\frac{1}{(N+1)^d}||\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}^d, m_i\leqslant N}\chi_m^{-1} U(m)v||^2 dm$.

I guess we should pass to the Limit $T\rightarrow\infty$, but I am not too sure how to do it in Detail.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: what do you mean by $U$ is cyclic? I though that meant that $H = \langle\{U(m)v\}_m\rangle$. Is that so or is it something else

Comment: @ConradoCosta it does mean this, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Let's fix some notations.

Denote the Haar measure on $\Bbb{T}^d$ by $\lambda$ instead of $m$.

The measures suggested should probably be normalized by
$$ d\mu_{v,N}(y)=\frac{1}{(2N+1)^d}\left\|\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}^d, \lvert
m_i \rvert \leq N}\chi_{-m}(y) U(m)v\right\|^2 d\lambda(y).$$

The characters of $\Bbb{T}^d$ are the functions
$$\chi_m: \Bbb{T}^d  \to C^*\\
y \mapsto e^{2\pi i m \cdot y}$$

Finally, introduce the shorthand notation for the truncated sums
$$\sum_{m \le N} f(m) := \sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}^d, \lvert m_i\rvert \leq N} f(m).$$

With this, we have
\begin{align*}
\left\| \sum_{m\le N} \chi_{-m}(y) U(m)v\right\|^2 &
  = \bigg\langle \sum_{m \le N} \chi_{-m}(y) U(m)v, \sum_{k\le N} \chi_{-k}(y) U(k)v\bigg\rangle \\
& = \sum_{m\le N} \sum_{k \le N} \big\langle\chi_{-m}(y) U(m)v,\chi_{-k}(y) U(k)v\big\rangle \\
& = \sum_{m\le N} \sum_{k \le N} \chi_{k-m}(y)\big\langle U(-k)U(m)v, v\big\rangle \\
& = \sum_{m\le N} \sum_{k \le N}e^{2\pi i (k-m) \cdot y}\big\langle U(m-k)v, v\big\rangle \\
\end{align*}

Now look at the terms
$T_l = e^{2\pi i l \cdot y}\big\langle U(l)v, v\big\rangle$
that appear from the change of variables $l = m - k$.
The peak contribution to the sum comes from $l = 0$ (with $(2N + 1)^d$
terms),
and they decay as $\lvert l\rvert$ increases,
until when some coordinate becomes greater than $2N$, when it vanishes.

Therefore, the mean defining $d\mu_{v,N}(y)$ corresponds to a Cèsaro sum of the Fourier series
$$\sum_{l\le N} e^{2\pi i l \cdot y}\big\langle U(l)v, v\big\rangle.$$
Thus $d\mu_{v,N}(y)$ converges to a (tempered) distribution $T$.

A calculation shows that
$\langle T, \chi_j\rangle = \langle U(j) v, v\rangle$,
first integrating on the torus $\Bbb{T}^d$ to get only terms where $m-k =
j$,
and then taking the limit as $N\to\infty$.
Let's see why: the definition of $\langle T, \chi_j\rangle$ is the limit as $N\to\infty$ of
$$ \frac{1}{(2N+1)^d} \sum_{m\le N} \sum_{k \le N} \int_{\Bbb{T}^d}
 \chi_j (y) \chi_{k-m}(y) \big\langle U(m-k)v, v\big\rangle \, d\lambda(y).
$$
The orthogonality of the characters $\chi_j$ and $\chi_{m-k}$ over $\Bbb{T}^d$ reduce the sum to only
$$ \frac{1}{(2N+1)^d} \sum_{m,k\le N \, m-k = j} \big\langle U(m-k)v, v\big\rangle.
$$
Now, a volume argument shows that for each fixed $j$,
as $N\to\infty$, the number of solutions to $m-k = j$ with all coordinates of $m$ and $k$ smaller than $N$ is equal to $(2N+1)^d$ up to error terms of degree $d-1$ in $N$.

This establishes the functional calculus to the trigonometric polynomials,
with the uniform bound
$\lvert\langle T, P\rangle\rvert \leq \sup_{y\in \Bbb{T}^d} P(y)$.
With this bound, we can both extend the functional calculus
to all continuous funtions,
and by the Riesz-Markov theorem this distribution
is in fact a measure $\mu$ on $\Bbb{T}^d$.

To conclude, we note that the isometry between the spaces $L^2(\mu)$ and $H$
is given by the linear map
$$ \mathcal{U}: L^2(\mu) \to H\\
 P \mapsto P(U)v $$
constructed by the functional calculus above.
This is an isometry since
$$\langle P, Q\rangle_{L^2(\mu)} =
  \int_{\Bbb{T}^d} P(y) \bar{Q}(y) \, d\mu(y) =
  \langle P(U) Q(U)^* v, v\rangle_H =
  \langle Q(U)^* P(U) v, v\rangle_H =
  \langle P(U)v, Q(U)v\rangle_H. $$
(We used the commutativity of all $U(m)$ and $U^*(m)$, since they are unitary, to commute also $P(U)$ and $Q^*(U)$)

Since $v$ is cyclic, the function $\mathcal{U}$ is onto $H$,
so indeed we have an isomorphism of Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 1):

*(note that you are using $m$ for two different things; I will just ignore the Haar measure as I don't think it is needed)*

Since the characters $\chi_m$ evaluate at single points $m\in\mathbb Z^d\cap\mathbb T^d$ (which are the $d$-tuples consisting of $1$ and $-1$) , you have
$$
\int_{\mathbb T^d}\chi_m\,d\mu_v=\mu_v(\{m\}).
$$
And you want this to equal $\langle U(m)v,v\rangle$. So it is clear what the measure $\mu_v$ should be:
$$
\mu_v(X)=\sum_{m\in X\cap\mathbb Z^d}\,\langle U(m)v,v\rangle\,\delta_m.
$$
Then, for a fixed $m\in\mathbb Z^d\cap\mathbb T^d$,
$$
\int_{\mathbb T^d}\chi_m\,d\mu_v=\mu_v(\{m\})=\langle U(m)v,v\rangle.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you clarify the relation between your $\mu_v$ and the sequence of measures given in the question?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why you would want to consider those measures. They are diffuse measures, while the measure you want is necessarily atomic as you want it to be nonzero on singletons.

Comment: Martin, I know that there is a Notion of Limit for sequences of measures. Perhaps your $\mu_v$ is the Limit of These measures?

Comment: For something like that to work, you would have to multiply the Lebesgue measure by functions that tend to "peak" on the atoms of the limiting measure. But for your $\mu_{v,N}$ you seem to be multiplying the Lebesgue measure by a constant.